# Array results from power automate to virtual agent

Tags: power-automate, power-virtual-agents

I have created a chatbot which gets information from user. Based on user input it filters data from sharepoint lists and sends the result back to user. The output is dynamic in number of rows need to be sent to user. Also it should be in clickable format. In my current flow in Power Automate, I get the results in array. Problem comes when this array is sent to virtual agent which is sent directly as a single text but I need it in separate clickable cards.

Comment: So what’s the issue? Provide more detail otherwise this question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the string as a table with mark down. With the same mark down you can also create clickable links.

I have written a blog on the Power Users community which showcases both mark down examples in a Power Virtual Agent:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Copilot-Studio-Community-Blog/How-to-use-mark-down-to-format-a-table-for-the-bot-response/ba-p/1190942

Btw, Microsoft has rebranded Power Virtual Agents to Copilot studio.

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I want to get output as a clickable lists then could you please guide me further?

Comment: What do you mean by clickable lists? In the link I shared earlier the links within the table are clickable. What do you want to make clickable instead?